# Is there a public vagrant box available for Elementary OS Loki?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

Is there a public vagrant box available for Elementary OS Loki?

I couldn't find it on [vagrant cloud](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=elementary)

Answer (score 1):

The [TimWSpence/elementaryos](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/TimWSpence/boxes/elementaryos) box appears to be running Loki.

As you can probably tell, Vagrant boxes are not maintained by the elementary OS team and may not be updated as new releases come out.